# How to read full text in textfield

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

Currently i want to print out full text from my database, but it just print out 1 text, i don't know why and how to solve it, the code and image showed below::

```
print "<td><input name='taskname[]' type='text' size='225' value=".$db_field['task_name']." readonly=readonly></td>";
```

[image]

suppose it come out full text like "configure new problem" but it didn't, why would it happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place the value of the `value` attribute between quotes:

```
 value='".$db_field['task_name']."'
       ^                          ^
```

And since you are outputting content inside HTML, you also need to call [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on it:

```
 value='".htmlspecialchars($db_field['task_name'], ENT_QUOTES)."'
```

The second (encoding options) and third (text encoding of input) parameters of `htmlspecialchars` **must** be set to correct values; please take a look at the documentation determine which ones are correct for you.

Comment: ya your are right, i also figured out should put ''between the value, thanks man